# how to shut down android app completely so all of it memory will be reclaimed?

Tags: android

im working on an app that have only 1 main activity.

the app create a new thread that execute c++ code, once the thread returns i need to close the app completely so when the user try to use it again from any where in his phone, the app will open with no memory - like it have been removed from the background and freshly started.

when calling `activity.finish()` the app is not fully destroyed, so i have added `System.exit(1)` in the end of the `OnDestroy` method, but that caused rare **ANR** reports from google play that i could not reproduce.

**my question is:**

how can i shutdown the app completely the right way without causing any anr/stuck partial locks or any thing else?

in the anr report the c++ thread doesnt exist - it returned - hence im highly sure it caused by app close logic

**anr logs:**

```
#00  pc 00000000000177ac  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 00000000000b643d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
#02  pc 00000000003f045b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+230)
#03  pc 00000000003f034b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+8)
#04  pc 000000000062c225  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+152)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:615)
at jz.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:2)
at xm.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060)
at xi.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:6)
at no.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:3)
at on.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:10)
at on.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:1)
at pe.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:1)
at pb.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:19)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.safebrowsing.b.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:7)
at pb.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:53)
- locked <0x06c91611> (a java.lang.Object)
at op.g (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:11)
at op.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:30)
at pe.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:7)
at oa.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:3)
at rw.m_ (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060)
at rj.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:14)
at rb.c (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060)
at rc.handleMessage (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060:35)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at vw.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060)
 at vw.dispatchMessage (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20461004@20461004.264725060.264725060)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: I dont think you can, because it will imply to give a direct order to the java virtual machine (Dalvikm or ANT) and that is protected. The java virtual machine is in charge of prioritizing the foreground process so the user can have the best experience while interacting with the UI. If is not completely close the machine doesnt need to kill it then.

Answer (score 0):

this is a partial answer;

If the portion of memory which you need wiped belongs to c++ code and you can manage it in your c++ code: just write a jni function which nulls the relative memory and pointers( it is permitted in c++) and call it before activity.finish;

If the portion of memory you need wiped belongs to c++ code and you can't manage it in your c++ code; fork and run the code in a new process; this would give you the ability to kill it( which wipes the memory) from the parent process's java code by calling:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(the_childs_process_id)
```